# How to connect Web Apps with VMs through more VNets

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I've a question about a network configuration.

I have a BizSpark account, that gives me 8 Azure subscriptions with some credit amounts. Between these subscriptions I've configured a private VNET composed by various VNETs for each of them, everyone with a specific gateway. We can say, for example, that I have two VNETs 10.10.0.0/16 and 10.11.0.0/16 interconnected site-to-site.

To the first gateway I've connected a Web App point-to-site, to the second VNET I've put a VM with database. The two are into two different subscriptions. The address of the VM will be for example 10.11.0.4. When I connect the Web App, the first gateway says "I'm destination for 10.10.0.0/16 net", but says nothing about others, so when the app will try to reach 10.11.0.4 it doesn't know where to look. It's a routing table problem.

How can I configure the Web App (or the gateway) for instruct properly the app's routing? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define "local networks" for the VNets you want to interconnect and add the "target local network" to the corresponding VNet's gateway.

On the gateway for the Web App VNet you'll need to define a local network connection for 10.11.0.0/16 and on the VM VNet gateway a local network for 10.10.0.0/16.

Details and links reference documentation [here](https://serverfault.com/a/630609).

Comment: Vnets are already interconnected with "local networks". This is a routing table problem from the web app side, that is connected with a point-to-site, so in an other network, sample: 192.168.1.0/24

Comment: @tmm360 Ah, I see. I don't think the gateway allows for routing packets from point-to-site VPN connections to other VNets. You'll probably need to proxy the connections if you want to reach beyond the VNet with a point-to-site VPN.